# Debug node.js in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-2017

I can only choose Browsers for debugging JavaScript in Visual Studio 2017.

How can I add node.js for Run or Debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Click on Debug in left side menu and then click on settings icon. A list will be displayed you will choose nodejs for nodejs and it will open lauch.json with configurations like this for a workspace

```
{
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\app.js"
    }
```

Here you can replace app.js with your server file.

Comment: I find no Debug in left side menu.
Are you talking about 2017 or Code ?
I'm searching whole 2017, can't find some setting Web- oder Node-Project.